# Pandas slicing excluding the end

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

When slicing a dataframe using loc,

df.loc[start:end]

both start and end are included. Is there an easy way to exclude the end when using loc?

Comment: why not `df.loc[start:end-1]`

Comment: @WonjinKim Presumably because their index isn't integers. And @OP, in principle you should  probably just be using the inclusive interval as an inclusive interval - i.e. if you don't need the endpoint, change your control flow such that you pass `end` as being the last index you _do_ want.

Comment: In my case, the index is datetime object. So end-1 is not allowed. Moreover end - datetime.timedelta(days=1) does not work either because the index does not contain every day.

Answer (score 21):

Easiest I can think of is `df.loc[start:end].iloc[:-1]`.

Chops off the last one.

Comment: Thanks, so `iloc` wouldn't include the last one?

Comment: this works assuming `end` is indeed part of your index. With datetimes it can backfire.

Answer (score 17):

[`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) includes both the start and end, one less ideal work around is to get the index position and use `iloc` to slice the data frame (assume you don't have duplicated index):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]}, index = ['a','b','c','d'])

df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('a'):df.index.get_loc('c')]

#   A
#a  1
#b  2

df.loc['a':'c']

#   A
#a  1
#b  2
#c  3
```

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I was doing. I was worried about the performance issue when index gets really long. I guess there is no way around this.

Comment: I have no sure say about the performance. But query related to index is usually optimized and fast.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers addresses the situation where `end` is not part of the index.
The more general solution is simply comparing the index to `start` and `end`, that way you can enforce either of them being inclusive of exclusive.

```py
df[(df.index >= start) & (df.index < end)]
```

For instance:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.arange(48),
        "y": np.arange(48) * 2,
    },
    index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01 00:00:00", freq="1H", periods=48)
)

>>> start = "2020-01-01 14:00"
>>> end = "2020-01-01 19:30" # this is not in the index

>>> df[(df.index >= start) & (df.index < end)]

                    x   y
2020-01-01 14:00:00 14  28
2020-01-01 15:00:00 15  30
2020-01-01 16:00:00 16  32
2020-01-01 17:00:00 17  34
2020-01-01 18:00:00 18  36
2020-01-01 19:00:00 19  38
```

Comment: Please, be cautious with this solution. Even though it's correct, it will take MUCH longer.
In my case, instead of 1 second operation, it worked 20 seconds per call for the index.

Comment: @dmitry502 that's correct - thanks for underlying it. There's clearly a trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

For slicing a `DatetimeIndex`, you can try this. It will grab everything up to one nanosecond before your end time. This will exclude the end time (assuming you aren't using ns precision), but not necessarily the last time.

```
df.loc[start:(end - pd.Timedelta('1ns'))]
```

Comment: Although this is very basic, there's some merit in this solution. (a) it's obvious what's happening and (b) you don't have to worry about the end of the range not being in the index (chopping off the last element is a terrible idea for this reason), and (c) it shouldn't suffer from performance like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62134203/2071807) does.

Comment: I just tried this solution on pandas 1.3.5: using "1ns" I'm still having the end time included (maybe due to some rounding issue), while using "1ms" (or "1s") it is successfully excluded

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) can be used instead for slicing indices with `.loc` with an exclusive stop *provided that* the index has integer dtype. Here is a straightforward helper:

```py
class _eidx:
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> pd.RangeIndex:
        return pd.RangeIndex(s.start, s.stop, s.step)
eidx = _eidx()
```

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": range(10), "y": range(10, 20)})

print(df.loc[eidx[3:5]])
```

```
   x   y
3  3  13
4  4  14
```

An even simpler way is just using python `range`:

```py
print(df.loc[range(3, 5)])
```

```
   x   y
3  3  13
4  4  14
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any really neat way to do this, but I would favour solutions which are expressive (is it clear what I'm trying to do?).

For this reason, I like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69655142/2071807) even though it's somewhat basic and a bit clumsy.

A more robust, expressive and, I think, performant version of this same idea would be to first create the inclusive slice, then filter the result to exclude the end-point:

```py
df.loc[start:end][lambda _: _.index != end]
```

This solution is reasonably fast (I've set `s = start; e = end`) and done it with a Series called `ts`:

```py
In [1]: %timeit ts[s:e]
135 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit ts[(ts.index >= s) & (ts.index < e)]
45.1 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit ts[s:e][lambda s: s.index != e]
299 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

It can be made even more readable by allowing an intermediate variable:

```py
inclusive = df.loc[start:end]
exclusive = inclusive[inclusive.index != end]
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using the datatime value from the index of another dataframe. lets assume your the datetime values you want to use is df1.index[0], you can get resolution of that index using df1.index[0].resolution.

```
end = df1.index[0]
df.loc[:(end-end.resolution)]
```