# Why does .loc have inclusive behavior for slices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

For some reason, the following 2 calls to `iloc` / `loc` produce different behavior:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(3), B=range(3)))
>>> df.iloc[:1]
   A  B
0  0  0
>>> df.loc[:1]
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
```

I understand that `loc` considers the row labels, while `iloc` considers the integer-based indices of the rows. But why is the upper bound for the `loc` call considered inclusive, while the `iloc` bound is considered exclusive?

Comment: Think about `list(range(1))` , will only give back 0 , .iloc will select more than (not no less )

Comment: They also specify this behavior explicitly in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing). Right under the `.loc` documentation: "◦A slice object with labels 'a':'f', (note that contrary to usual python slices, both the start and the stop are included!)"

Comment: The real "answer" should be that `loc` should be a single function that allows one to specify either numerics or names.  I tried to post a use case of why this is a big issue (in short, we often want to use numeric rows and column names), but that posting immediately got deleted as a "duplicate" of this.  This is a big issue with pandas!!  It causes many bugs, and ugly code.

Comment: Hey @MikeWilliamson - if they were merged, would you want their slicing to be end-exclusive or end-inclusive?

Comment: @ASGM I feel like it should match all other Python styes: it is start-inclusive and end-exclusive.  Eg, `list(range(2,9))` is `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.  I feel like all Python libraries should follow Python's standards, which will lead to best adaptation of the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

It often makes more sense to do end-inclusive slicing when using labels, because it requires less knowledge about other rows in the DataFrame.

Whenever you care about labels instead of positions, end-exclusive label slicing introduces position-dependence in a way that can be inconvenient.

---

**Longer answer:**

Any function's behavior is a trade-off: you favor some use cases over others.  Ultimately the operation of `.iloc` is a subjective design decision by the Pandas developers (as the comment by @ALlollz indicates, this behavior [is intentional](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)).  But to understand why they might have designed it that way, think about what makes label slicing different from positional slicing.

Imagine we have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(X=range(4)), index=['a','b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(X=range(3)), index=['b','c','z'])
```

`df1` contains:

```
   X

a  0
b  1
c  2
d  3
```

`df2` contains:

```
   X

b  0
c  1
z  2
```

Let's say we have a label-based task to perform: we want to get rows between `b` and `c` from both `df1` and `df2`, and we want to do it using the same code for both DataFrames.  Because `b` and `c` don't have the same positions in both DataFrames, simple positional slicing won't do the trick.  So we turn to label-based slicing.

**If `.loc` were end-exclusive**, to get rows between `b` and `c` we would need to know not only the label of our desired end row, *but also the label of the next row after that*.  As constructed, this next label would be different in each DataFrame.

In this case, we would have two options:

- Use separate code for each DataFrame: `df1.loc['b':'d']` and `df2.loc['b':'z']`.  This is inconvenient because it means we need to know extra information beyond just the rows that we want.
- For either dataframe, get the positional index first, add 1, and then use positional slicing: `df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('b'):df.index.get_loc('c')+1]`.  This is just wordy.

**But since `.loc` is end-inclusive**, we can just say `.loc['b':'c']`. Much simpler!

Whenever you care about labels instead of positions, and you're trying to write position-independent code, *end-exclusive label slicing re-introduces position-dependence in a way that can be inconvenient*.

That said, maybe there are use cases where you really do want end-exclusive label-based slicing.  If so, you can use [@Willz's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49416048/2074981):

```
df.loc[start:end].iloc[:-1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be df.loc[start:end].iloc[:, :-1]?
Right now it is just excluding the last row instead of the last column

Comment: @Suhas not sure I understand your comment: the OP's example was about rows, so excluding the last row is the intended behavior.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I understand this behavior is intentional... but it is still "wrong".  I feel like someone decided something like, "folks coming from R will like inclusive better, and they will use names more often".

But we will all spend far more time *programming in Python* than *learning Python* (or any language, library, or framework).  So, while the learning curve might be *marginally* higher, API consistency is far more important.  This is just a bad design decision that will *rightfully* cause users to accidentally make off-by-one errors when refactoring.  :(

Comment: That rant being said, I love `pandas` and I think it is great.  I use it all the time.  I just wish if these sorts of "mistakes" could be openly discussed and fixed.  I tried to submit a bug report for this, and another similar "mistake by choice", and I was chased out of the discussion within minutes.

Comment: While I think that the existing behavior is good (for reasons other than learnability, as outlined in my answer), I think it's a valid subject for discussion.  Apologies if you've already tried this, but perhaps you'd get more traction submitting a `Feature Request` instead of a `Bug Report`?

Comment: df.loc[df.index.get_loc('b'):df.index.get_loc('c')+1] this slice does not seem to work. I dont think its correct logic for .loc

Comment: @AkshaySapra you're right, fixed it! Thanks for catching!

Comment: This sentence might be buggy : "end-inclusive label slicing re-introduces position-dependence in a way that can be inconvenient."

Comment: Happy to edit it @Korchkidu; can you be a bit more specific about what's wrong with it?

Comment: @ASGM: because label slicing is position independent. So this sentence might be misleading.

Comment: @Korchkidu is right IMO.

The Quick answer says:
"Whenever you care about labels instead of positions, end-exclusive label slicing introduces position-dependence in a way that can be inconvenient."
which I agree with.

But in the Long answer is a different statement:
"Whenever you care about labels instead of positions, and you're trying to write position-independent code, end-inclusive label slicing re-introduces position-dependence in a way that can be inconvenient."
Where is a typo probably: "end-inclusive" should be replaced with "end-exclusive".

Cannot Edit at the moment.

Comment: @tomek and Korchkidu thanks for pointing out the mistake! Have fixed!