# Edit multiple values with df.at()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why does

```
>>> offset = 2
>>> data = {'Value': [7, 9, 21, 22, 23, 100]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>>> df.at[:offset, "Value"] = 99
>>> df
Value
0   99
1   99
2   99
3   22
4   23
5   100
```

change values in indices [0, 1, 2]? I would expect them only to be changed in [0, 1] to be conform with regular slicing.

Like when I do

```
>>> arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> arr[0:2]
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.at` behaves like `.loc`, in that it selects rows/columns by label. Label slicing in pandas is inclusive. Note that `.iloc`, which performs slicing on the integer positions, behaves like you would expect. See [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49962706/2246849) for a motivation.

Also note that the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) suggests to use .at only when selecting/setting single values. Instead, use `.loc`.

Answer (score 0):

On line 4, when you say `:2`, it means all rows from 0 to 2 or `0:2`. If you want to change only the 3rd row, you should change it to `2:2`

Comment: Am I totally wrong or does normally in Python [0:2] means excluding the 2? I added a minimal example using a list.

Comment: 0:2 here would means row (or columns) numbers - 0,1 and 2, which is the first 3 items. The minus one is in cases like - If you ask for say the length of a dataframe ````len(df)```` for eg, it would return 6 and the indexes would be from 0 to 5. Hope this helps