# Slicing MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe with integer values incorrect?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, numpy-slicing

We have a MultiIndex DataFrame where the top-level index uses integer values.  Slicing for a specific value returns all index values up to the requested value, not just the requested value.  Is this a bug, or are we doing it wrong?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2], ['A', 'B']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape((len(midx), 1)), index=midx, columns=['Values'])

df.loc[(slice(1), slice(None)), :]  # Slice for only top index value=1
```

This first slice returns just the index values = 1, as expected:

```
        Values
1   A   0
1   B   1
```

But:

```
df.loc[(slice(2), slice(None)), :]  # Slice for only top index value=2
```

returns index value 1 as well as value 2, like this:

```
        Values
1   A   0
1   B   1
2   A   2
2   B   3
```

where we expect this:

```
        Values
2   A   2
2   B   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `slice(x)`, `x` is the *stop* value (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)); so it will return everything up and including that value. In your case you can simply supply the desired index directly:

```py
df.loc[(2, slice(None)), :]
```

Output:

```
     Values
2 A       2
  B       3
```

Note that in calls to `.loc`, slice end values are *inclusive*; see the [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-endpoints-are-inclusive) and this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49962417/9473764).

Answer (score 3):

You need `slice(2, 2)` to extract the 2nd index, when providing only one parameter, it's [treated as `stop` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) so everything before that index is returned:

```
df.loc[(slice(2, 2), slice(None)), :]
#     Values
#2 A       2
#  B       3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`pd.Dataframe.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas-dataframe-xs) like this:

```
df.xs(2, level=0, drop_level=False)
```

Output:

```
     Values
2 A       2
  B       3
```